# TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force'

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, bilstm

I use word2vec and biLstm to implement sentiment analysis for movie reviews. When I train my model on Jupyter notebook, I always get the **TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force'** at the last batch of the first epoch.

here is my code:

```
batch_size = 50
result = model.fit(
    X_train,
    Y_train,
    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=5
)
```

and the error:

```
Train on 1600 samples, validate on 400 samples
Epoch 1/5
1550/1600 [============================>.] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.7257 - acc: 0.4961
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-360-8eaf5ac2ad33> in <module>()
     17     validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
     18     batch_size=batch_size,
---> 19     epochs=5
     20 )

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/WDPS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    958                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    959                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 960                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
    961 
    962     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/WDPS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1648                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1649                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1650                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1651 
   1652     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/WDPS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1231                             for l, o in zip(out_labels, val_outs):
   1232                                 epoch_logs['val_' + l] = o
-> 1233             callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
   1234             if callback_model.stop_training:
   1235                 break

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/WDPS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
     71         logs = logs or {}
     72         for callback in self.callbacks:
---> 73             callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
     74 
     75     def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/WDPS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    304                 self.log_values.append((k, logs[k]))
    305         if self.verbose:
--> 306             self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values, force=True)
    307 
    308 

TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force'
```

At first, I have a line of code **verbose = 1** under the **epochs=5**. There will be the same error and the arrow point to **verbose = 1**. Then I change it to **verbose=2** or just delete **verbose**. But I still have the problem.

I tried to change the batch size and the amount of training set. but it still didn't work out.

It always showed at the last batch.

python version= 3.6.2
keras version = 2.1.1

Comment: It looks like this bit of code using `force=True` was removed in [keras 2.1.4](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/compare/2.1.1...2.1.4). This is a fairly old version of keras, so you could try updating. Alternatively, the default for `verbose` might also be 1, so you could try setting it to 0 rather than deleting it.

Comment: I have tried to upgrade the keras to both 2.6.0 and 2.7.0, still have the problem. But it worked out when I made the `verbose = 0`.

Comment: Thank you so much!